# Where are the irrationals in this set?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, real-numbers, cantor-set

Let's define a sequence of families of sets inside $[0, 1]$ interval:

$$
F_n= \left\{ \left(\frac{j-1}{2^n},\frac{j}{2^n}\right] \mid \forall j \in \{ 1, \cdots, 2^n\} \wedge n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
$$

Now, we know that $[0, 1] = \{0\} \cup(0, 1]$. Now we are goint to define a new set $S_n$ as follow:

$$
S_n = \bigcup_{X \in F_n} X
$$

For me it's clear that $S_n = (0, 1]$ as long as $n$ is a natural fixed number, and so, it contains all irrational numbers in $(0, 1]$. The question is: does $S_\infty$ contain the irrationals? It is obvious that this set is not empty and contains rationals numbers. Now the questions:

1. Does $S_\infty$ loses the irrationals?
2. Are all rationals contained in the set $S_\infty$?
3. Is $S_\infty = (0,1]$??

**Many** thanks in advance!!!

---

(RE)$^2$EDIT: Lets define $S_\infty$. Let's start defining $F_\infty$:

$$
F_\infty = \{ x \in (0, 1] \; | \; x \in X_j \wedge X_j \in F_n \; \text{with} \; j \leq n \; \forall n, j \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$

This implies $F_\infty$ would become a infinite (but countable?) partition of $(0,1]$ in disjoint subsets containing just a point. So, $S_\infty$ would just be:

$$
S_n = \bigcup_{X \in F_\infty} X
$$

Thanks @Zev Chonoles and @Asaf Karagila for the useful comments!

Comment: How do you define $\lim$ for sets?

Comment: $S_n = (0, 1]$ for every $n$, so this question doesn't make much sense - but the limiting processes involved aren't too problematic $\ddot{\smile}$, unless  (and this is probably the real point of the question) you want to define some kind of limit of the $F_n$. Over to Carlos to clarify this.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Got it. I have in mind the way. Edit in progress. Spoiler: infinite intersection of all members of the sequence of sets $\{S_1, S_2, ..., S_n, ...\}$

Comment: Well, then, take a deep breath, and now figure out the answer on your own. Then, to dispel any confusion leftovers, recall that a lot of things in mathematics are not continuous. And there is no reason to expect that a limit of a *constant* sequence will be any different.

Comment: You still haven't gotten around the fact that $S_n = (0,1]$ for each $n$. The intersection of a set with itself, no matter whether you intersect the set with itself finitely many times or infinitely many times, is still the same set. So if $S_\infty$ is the intersection of all the sets $\{S_1 = (0,1], S_2 = (0,1], ...\}$ then $S_\infty = (0,1]$.

Comment: Notation failure. Editing now. Thanks!

Comment: Your new definition fails you as well. For $n\neq m$ we have that $F_n\cap F_m=\varnothing$. So the intersection is a subset of $F_1\cap F_2$ which is pretty much empty, so it has to be empty as well.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Arrrrg!!! True again!! Do you know what I mean, right? I'm trying to figure out how to write it. Give me a second and I will find the way. Just to not confuse others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: Your $F_\infty$ is very unclear.

Comment: How to define that $F_\infty$?? It is very clear in my mind, but I can't find the correct combination of symbols. This last one is inspired in you answer, but it is true:  it is not the limit  of the sequence $F_n$. I need to sleep or tomorrow I'll be a zombie in the lab, but I'll find the way. And I think I have the answer and now I can imagine that the answer can be (0,1], but tomorrow I'll write it down here.

Answer (score 4):

You have defined a set $S_n$ for each natural number $n$; however, you have not defined a set $S_\infty$ since $\infty$ is not a natural number.

It is an understandable and common mistake to assume that doing some operation, or defining some object, for each natural number $n$ necessarily results in some "limiting" operation or object for when "$n=\infty$". However this is usually either not possible at all, or it is quite subtle to do.

Comment: It is even more common to automatically assume that all our definitions are continuous unless proven otherwise. Namely, if you defined something, that the limit *will* be the limit of the definitions. We see this in the case of "the power set of the natural numbers is the union of power sets of its initial segments", or in other similar definitions like that which "challenge" basic set theoretic truths.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles Thanks for the comment! I hope my edit solves your point : )

Answer (score 4):

Recall that if $A=B$ then $A\cap B=A=B$. Just as well, if $A_n=A$ for all $n$, then $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n=A$.

This shouldn't be surprising, if $x_n=x$ for all $n$, then $\lim x_n=x$. We are *not* surprised by this at all.

What *is* supposedly surprising here, is that the intuition we have is inherently discontinuous, and this is a result of infinity not being intuitive. We expect that when we reach infinity, we make "the leap" across the chasm which lies between the finite and infinite. But a limit means only reaching to the edge of the chasm, not actually leaping across. Continuity is what helps us to cross-over when things are "nice enough". But not everything is continuous.

Okay, I digress a bit into metaphors.

Let's get back to your question. You expect that the set $S_\infty$ will be a set where we already refined all the intervals, and this is most certainly not the intersection of all the $S_n$'s. This is something finer than that. It seems that what you expect is that $S_\infty$ will be the set whose members lie in an intersection "along a branch" of the tree of intervals. Namely, it seems that you expect that $$x\in S_\infty\iff\exists f\colon\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\text{ with }f(n)<2^n,\text{ such that }\forall n,\ x\in\left(\frac{f(n)}{2^n},\frac{f(n)+1}{2^n}\right].$$

Sure, we can define it this way, but just note that this is *not* the limit of the sequence of sets $S_n$, and very much *not* the intersection of that sequence of sets.

Note that this is not *too* different from the common mistake the $\bigcup\Bbb Q^n$ and $\Bbb{Q^N}$ are two distinct sets, and exactly one of them is uncountable.

Comment: I'm in right now

Comment: Dear Asaf, my problem arises from the fact that $\bigcap [a, a+\frac{1}{n}) = \{a\}$. And I've thought in this problem seeing the infinite intersection of the "branches path" of nested intervals, and accepting that you will end up always in a number as defined in the closed frontier of the interval; and because I've defined such numbers as rationals, I've assumed that at the end you would end up with a collection of rationals (2-adics, I think). Can you understand my point?

Comment: But you are not intersecting $[a,a+\frac1n)$.

Comment: Choose $j=2^n$ and you will get the following nested intervals: $\left(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},\frac{2^n}{2^n}\right] = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n},1 \right]$, which is the same case as exposed. This is what is in my mind and the main motivation for this problem.

Comment: Because when you make the infinite intersection of all these nested intervals, increasing $n$, you end up with just {1}. And this is just because we have chosen j to be equal to $2^n$, but you can choose another value for j and you will end up with the same problem.

Comment: You have uncountably many possible functions.

Comment: With uncountably you mean that the set $F_\infty$ is uncontable and it should contain irrationals, right?

Comment: There are uncountably many functions which give you paths of intervals. Each of these have a non-empty intersection of a single point. Now you should ask yourself, can two paths end up with the same number? If they differ, then this means that at some point we had two disjoint intervals that we choose each path to proceed in each interval. But that means that the intersection cannot lead us to the same point. So the map from these "branches" to points in the "limit" is in fact a bijection. So the set of points described in my answer, which I think is what *you* had in mind, is uncountable.